# Login session timeout in Spring

Tags: spring, session

This is my login method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<User> login(HttpServletRequest request){
         request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(10);
         ...
    }
```

I setted the session timeout at 10 seconds for my tests. But this doesn't work. How I can make the session invalid after a specific time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity login(HttpServletRequest request, **HttpSession session**){
            **session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10);**
    }

Comment: Doesn't work. After 10 seconds I can access again the site. Another idea?